# RadGridView Not displaying List

Tags: c#

I have a basic List, and added in values manually. My question is "Why is it showing the value length rather than value"

```
List<string> DateIntervaList = new List<string>();
    DateIntervaList.Add("1");
    DateIntervaList.Add("2");
    DateIntervaList.Add("11");
    DateIntervaList.Add("12");
Grid.ItemsSource = DateIntervalList;
```

This returns in a column with the values [1][1][2][2] rather than 1,2,11,12.

Comment: I think it is because string implements IEnumerable<T>, the grid then binds to List<IEnumerable> and probably returns the first element of the "inner list" (first character in the string) and displays it in the cell.

Comment: Ahhh okay, May I ask do you know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple help-class:

```
public class GridItem {
  public string Content{ get; set; }
}
```

....

```
List<string> DateIntervaList = new List<string>();

DateIntervaList.Add( new GridItem(){ Content = "1" } );
DateIntervaList.Add( new GridItem(){ Content = "2" } );
DateIntervaList.Add( new GridItem(){ Content = "11" } );
DateIntervaList.Add( new GridItem(){ Content = "12" } );

Grid.ItemsSource = DateIntervalList;
```